# R: get the percentage of day comprised between two timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp

I'm trying to get the percentage of the day comprised between two timestamps.

In my case, I have the following timestamps: `2020-05-03 23:30:04` and `2020-05-03 23:43:37`

So my interval is 13 minutes, which means the 0.9 % of the day, approximately.

How could I calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I've came up with this solution (in the case of a dataframe):

```
timeseries= timeseries %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(diff_min = difftime(tsEnd,tsBegin,units="mins"),
                percentage_day = (diff_min / 1440) * 100)
```

Where `tsBegin` contains `2020-05-03 23:30:04` and `tsEnd` contains `2020-05-03 23:43:37`

I divide the difference in minutes by `1440` as this is the number of minutes in a day.